# Windows CLion fonts look weird

Tags: windows, fonts, ide, clion

I am using CLion using the font *Inconsolata*, however the font looks weird on CLion compared to other text editors such as Komodo Edit.

I would appreciate if anyone can show me how to make the font on CLion look like it does on Komodo:

[image]